# Google Map with Directions - Can I do this without form tags?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When you embed a Google Map and add a 'get directions' form to it you end up with code like this...

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d75485.70101136623!2d-3.058063457690749!3d53.755162332426345!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487b402d5a3f1869%3A0xfb31e87322fd8f2c!2sLytham+St+Annes+FY8!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1458126515953" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<h3>Directions</h3>
<form action="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/" method="get">
<p><label for="saddr">Your postcode</label>
<input type="text" name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
<input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="fy8" />
<input type="hidden" name="hl" value="en" /></p>
</form>
```

Now, I'm trying to add this, using a 'Raw HTML' widget to an ASP.net page. Long story but we don't have any other way to do it at present. This widget strips out the form tags, so I need to try and rewrite the above probably by adding some kind of onclick event to the submit button that does the equivalent of the form's action="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/" method="get" attributes.

Is this possible in javascript and if so can anyone point me in the right direction to solving it?

Many thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, when I say "strips out the form tags" I mean only the start and end form tags with their attributes, not the input or label tags between them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it. The map iframe part is irrelevant.

```
<p><label for="saddr">Your postcode</label>
<input type="text" name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" />
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Go" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.co.uk/maps/?daddr=' + document.getElementById('daddr').value +'&saddr=' + document.getElementById('saddr').value;" />
<input type="hidden" name="daddr"  id="daddr" value="fy8 2er" />
<input type="hidden" name="hl" value="en" /></p>
```